# How to succeed in Alien Hive?

Tags: alien-hive

Alien Hive is an Android/iOS puzzle game.
I have played around 10 times per 15-30 minutes, spent few hours in total, but the best achievement was `x5` and two hives. I'm so far from unlocking even the first alien, that I'm starting to think, that it's impossible to open them in a hundred of years without paying money.

Answer (score 1):

I have unlocked 3 supreme aliens thus far. For each of them I had to use about 20-23 magic fruit to evolve the eggs,babys,etc fast enough within the energy limit. So it's just a matter of farming fruits for several runs and some gold to buy them if necessary. Bot killer is also useful.

Once you evolve a supreme alien, it is unlocked as a power-up in the roulette before playing.

They also have levels, but still couldn't find out how to level-up them.